# How to make use Task.WaitAll with async method using C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

I have used `Task.WaitAll` inside an `async` method in my `HomeController`, but it is not waiting to complete  execution of the `async` methods. What did I do wrong here? Instead of waiting, it immediately goes to the next statement.

HomeController.cs:

```
private List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        SendMessages();
    }

    Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
    // call demo method
}

private async Task SendMessages()
{
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessMessages()
    taskList.Add(task);
}

private async Task ProcessMessages()
{
    while (run for 10 minutes)
    {
        // data save
    }
}
```

I have added a `Task` into `taskList` and used `Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());` to wait for all tasks to complete, then `call demo method`. But instead of waiting and executing the whole loop, it immediately goes down after `Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());` and executes `call demo method`. Why is this?

Comment: Is there another line of `private List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();`? The current one defined in `Index `cannot be accessed to add tasks to by `SendMessages`. So it looks like you are waiting on an empty list of tasks.  Furthermore, you should use `await Task.WhenAll` instead of the blocking `WaitAll`

Comment: sorry `taskList` it is outside index()

Comment: @Neo, How are you implementing `run for 10 minutes` logic in ProcessMessages?

Comment: `var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

                while (DateTime.UtcNow - startTime < TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10))`

Comment: @Neo, shouldn't the logic to wait for 10 minutes be something like : `while((DateTime.UtcNow - startTime).TotalMinutes < 10) `. The code that you mentioned is not waiting for 10 minutes and therefore you see that the WaitAll method does not result in 10 minutes wait.

Comment: no its working for me with `Douglas` ans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Task.Factory.StartNew` should not be used to launch asynchronous operations, since it does not unwrap the returned `Task`, and instead returns a new `Task` that completes as soon as the asynchronous operation launches (or, more precisely, completes its synchronous part). You should use `Task.Run` instead.

Additionally, `SendMessages` should not be async. However, `Index` should be, allowing you to use the asynchronous `WhenAll` instead of the blocking `WaitAll`.

```
private List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
     for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     {
         SendMessages();
     }

     await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
     // call demo method
}

private void SendMessages()
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => ProcessMessagesAsync());   // here
    taskList.Add(task);
}

private async Task ProcessMessagesAsync()
{
    while (run for 10 minutes)
    {
        // data save
    }
}
```

Comment: ok I have made Index async and SendMessages not async now... but why not use waitall and why not SendMessages not async? pls tell me. thanks a lot

Comment: `WaitAll` would block the calling thread until all the tasks have completed, wasting it; whilst `WhenAll` would relinquish the thread and only resume execution when the tasks have completed. `SendMessages` does not need to be async since it doesn't have any await.